# 2d char array issue with placing an X on a board of 0s

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Okay, so I'm working on making a "Battle Bot" playing board and I need to show the location of the bot with an X on a board of 0's. However, I am finding that I cannot get the X to show up and I have no idea what is wrong.

Here is my code:

Starter Class

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProblemOne {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int size = scan.nextInt();
    int row = scan.nextInt();
    int column = scan.nextInt();
    int time = scan.nextInt();

    Board b = new Board(size, row, column, time);
    b.drawBoard();

  } 
}
```

Board class

```
public class Board {

char board[][];
int size, row, column, time;

public Board(int s, int r, int c, int t) {
    this.size = s;
    this.row = r;
    this.column = c;
    this.time = t;

    this.board = new char[size][size];

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            board[i][j] = '0';
        }
    }
}

public void placeBot(int r, int c) {

    r = row *= time;
    c = column *= time;

    if (r < size && c < size) {
        this.board[r][c] = 'X';
    }

}

public void drawBoard() {

    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < size; k++) {

            System.out.print(board[j][k]);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}

 }
```

However, when I put in the input for the size of the board, how many spaces the bot moves for rows and columns, and how many times it moves, all i get is:

```
 5
 1
 2
 2
 00000
 00000
 00000
 00000
 00000
```

as my output. I've altered various things and I can't figure out why the X will not appear on the board. Any suggestions would be lovely.

Comment: You never call `placeBot`.

Comment: How would I incorporate that?

Comment: Like you called `drawBoard`, you can call `b.placeBot(1,1)` per example, and recall `drawBoard` to see the new board.

Comment: Btw. what's the point of passing `r,c` to placeBot when you rewrite these values right away with something that does not depend on them at all?

What is the method supposed to do?

Comment: I did it because I would need to possibly pass in numbers through it for testing.

Comment: @user3113376 You will also need to check that both are > 0.

Comment: @ZouZou You mean >= 0.

Comment: @DavidKnipe Yes sorry for that. `>= 0` ! :)